# Xcode, Dev Docs Search Field Loosing Focus?

Tags: iphone, xcode, documentation

I am having a strange issue with the developer documentation (which i have only noticed after installing Xcode 3.2.3). My problem is that as you type in the search field (upper right) it looses focus and immediately starts looking for the first few letters you type. For example if you looking for "NSObject" you start typing "NSO" and as you type the field looses focus the last 5 characters "bject" just give beeps as you need to reselect the field to type extra characters. Has anyone else come across this or know what the problem might be?

cheers Gary.

Comment: I also noticed this. It doesn't happen every time, though, seems almost random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled this and found a reply from Apple regarding this problem in 3.2.2 (March 2010) "We are well aware of this and working on a fix. It's an interaction between existing code, the scripts built into the Document Sets, and a recent update to the WebKit framework." I would have thought 3.2.3 might have fixed it to be truthful.